# alternative to find for search and copy files?

Tags: bash, file-copy, locate

I have many files called `themes.txt` (but different in content) scattered in various folders.

I would like to use the `locate` command (not `find` !!!) to search for them and the `cp -backup` command to copy them to a folder called `/home/myhome/1`.

Is it possible with Linux Mint 20.3? If not, are there alternative solutions?

Comment: `locate` themes.txt will produce a list of all files, where the full path contains a match with themes.txt.
You should have a locate command in Mint 20.3.

Comment: Tell us your objective: Why the limitation?, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

If your `locate` supports the `-0` option (for NUL-delimited output) and `-e` (to do an extra check that the files still exist) and have GNU `cp` and `sort` and a `xargs` that supports `-r` and `-0` (all of which should be the case on Linux Mint):

```
LC_ALL=C locate -0e '*/themes.txt' |
  LC_ALL=C sort -zV |
  xargs -r0 cp -t ~/1 --backup=numbered
```

The `sort -V` is to get some non-random order (here version sort) in which the files will be copied, it's not necessary.

Instead of `locate -0e '*/themes.txt'`, to search for files called `themes.txt` exactly, you can also do `locate -0be '[t]hemes.txt'` which I find is a lot faster with the `mlocate` implementation (the `mlocate` manual mentions you can use `\themes.txt` instead of `'[t]hemes.txt`,  but that does not work with the `plocate` implementation at least).

Answer (score 0):

```
 cp --backup=numbered $(locate themes.txt) /home/myhome/1
```

Comment: This would break if any directory contained spaces or filename globbing characters.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, using `locate` for anything that requires parsing of its output is probably better done using `find` or a shell loop.  Partly due to the nature of Unix filenames (they may contain newlines) and partly due to the fact that the database that `locate` uses may be out of date.

You could do without both `find` and `locate` in `bash`:

```bsh
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob dotglob

for pathname in ./**/themes.txt; do
    cp -b "$pathname" ~/1/
done
```

This would first enable the use of the `**` globbing pattern, which matches across `/` in pathnames (and hence matches "recursively" into subdirectories).  It then enables `nullglob` to remove unmatched patterns and `dotglob` to allow patterns to match hidden names.

The loop iterates over all the names that you probably want to move, matching them in the current directory or in any subdirectory, and then copies each with `cp -b` (`-b` is the same as `--backup`) to the directory called `1` beneath your home directory.

This assumes that the current directory is not your home directory, as that would include the files in the destination directory.

If you know you onl/y have a few of these `themes.txt` files, you may use the command

```bsh
shopt -s globstar dotglob failglob
cp -b -t ~/1/ ./**/themes.txt
```

This uses `failglob` in place of `nullglob` to make the command fail gracefully if there are no matching names (the shell would not even try to run the command if the pattern didn't match any names).

Note that the above commands do not test whether the matched names are actually regular files (they could be directories, symbolic links, or any other type of non-regular file).  For that, you may use

```bsh
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob dotglob

for pathname in ./**/themes.txt; do
    if [ -f "$pathname" ] && [ ! -L "$pathname" ]; then
        cp -b "$pathname" ~/1/
    fi
done
```

This only copies regular files and avoids non-regular files and symbolic links to regular files.

---

With `find`, you would simply do

```bsh
find . -name themes.txt -type f -exec cp -b -t ~/1/ {} +
```

That is, call `cp -b -t ~/1/` with as many regular files called `themes.txt` as possible at a time from anywhere in the current directory or below.  This has the benefit of calling `cp` as few times as possible.